# Pulling collapsed summary report from data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, extract

Trying to update and summarize a larger data.table; data as follows.

```
    structure(list(y1_countyname = c("Montgomery County", "Elmore County", 
"Dallas County", "Chilton County", "Jefferson County", "Escambia County", 
"Escambia County", "Harris County"), n2 = c(867L, 835L, 115L, 
169L, 75L, 599L, 144L, 90L), y2_geoid = c("01001", "01001", "01001", 
"01001", "01001", "01003", "01003", "01003"), y1_geoid = c("01101", 
"01051", "01047", "01021", "01073", "12033", "01053", "48201"
), y2_ling_zo = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), y1_ling_zo = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 12L), ling_mig = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), grp_y2_geoid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), i7 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 599L, 144L, 0L), i9 = c(867L, 835L, 115L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), i11 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 169L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    i12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 90L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55ab0e577580>, sorted = c("y2_geoid", 
"y1_ling_zo"))

> in_1314_sub
       y1_countyname  n2 y2_geoid y1_geoid y2_ling_zo y1_ling_zo ling_mig
1: Montgomery County 867    01001    01101          9          9        0
2:     Elmore County 835    01001    01051          9          9        0
3:     Dallas County 115    01001    01047          9          9        0
4:    Chilton County 169    01001    01021          9         11        1
5:  Jefferson County  75    01001    01073          9         11        1
6:   Escambia County 599    01003    12033          9          7        1
7:   Escambia County 144    01003    01053          9          7        1
8:     Harris County  90    01003    48201          9         12        1
   grp_y2_geoid  i7  i9 i11 i12
1:            1   0 867   0   0
2:            1   0 835   0   0
3:            1   0 115   0   0
4:            1   0   0 169   0
5:            1   0   0  75   0
6:            2 599   0   0   0
7:            2 144   0   0   0
8:            2   0   0   0  90
```

the report I'm trying to append to:

```
structure(list(y1_countyname = c("Autauga County Non-migrants", 
"Baldwin County Non-migrants"), n2 = c(41198L, 148883L), y2_geoid = c("01001", 
"01003"), y1_geoid = c("01001", "01003"), y2_ling_zo = c(9L, 
9L), y1_ling_zo = c(9L, 9L), ling_mig = c(0, 0), nm_7 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), nm_9 = c(41198L, 148883L), nm_11 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), nm_12 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_), nm_15 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55ab0e577580>)

> in_1314_non_sof[, c(1:12)]
                 y1_countyname     n2 y2_geoid y1_geoid y2_ling_zo y1_ling_zo
1: Autauga County Non-migrants  41198    01001    01001          9          9
2: Baldwin County Non-migrants 148883    01003    01003          9          9
   ling_mig nm_7   nm_9 nm_11 nm_12 nm_15
1:        0   NA  41198    NA    NA    NA
2:        0   NA 148883    NA    NA    NA
```

using this:

```
in_1314_non_sof[, c('i7', 'i9', 'i11', 'i12'):= 
.(sum(in_1314_sub$n2[in_1314_sub$y1_ling_zo == 7L]),
 sum(in_1314_sub$n2[in_1314_sub$y1_ling_zo == 9L]),
 sum(in_1314_sub$n2[in_1314_sub$y1_ling_zo == 11L]),
 sum(in_1314_sub$n2[in_1314_sub$y1_ling_zo == 12L])),
 by = .(unique(in_1314_sub$grp_y2_geoid))]
```

results in:

```
in_1314_non_sof[, -c(8:12)]
                 y1_countyname     n2 y2_geoid y1_geoid y2_ling_zo y1_ling_zo
1: Autauga County Non-migrants  41198    01001    01001          9          9
2: Baldwin County Non-migrants 148883    01003    01003          9          9
   ling_mig  i7   i9 i11 i12
1:        0 743 1817 244  90
2:        0 743 1817 244  90
```

where hoped for results would be:

```
  i7   i9    i11  i12
  0   1817   244   0
 743   0      0    90
```

What am I missing to arrive at hoped for results. I don't think this is a duplicate of [conditional_collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458588/how-can-i-conditionally-collapse-groups-of-records-in-r-data-table); but, perhaps I've missed a useful `by` member.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a response to you, but now with your updated post, I'm confused. the sub table already has your columns i7, i9, i11, and i12, and the sum over any group can easily be obtained as `in_1314_sub[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=i7:i12, by=grp_y2_geoid]`.  Is that the grouping var that you want?

Comment: Yes, the `in_1314_sub` table does have `i7:i12`,  as I calculated and your above looks a cleaner approach than mine that I'll try. But the 'report' is 3141 rows and inputs to it vary between 40-90K rows, corresponding to activities between y2_geoid <=> y1_geoid, ie. migration, whose result, the report is summarizing. Don't know if that clarifies sufficiently.

Comment: And of course if you don't have i7:i12 calculated, it is simple to do so with `dcast(in_1314_sub[, sum(n2), by=.(y2_geoid,y1_ling_zo)],y2_geoid~y1_ling_zo, value_var="V1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated post, and using a more natural join,

```
in_1314_non_sof[, -c(8:12)][in_1314_sub[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=i7:i12, by=y2_geoid], on=.(y2_geoid)]
```

Output

```
                 y1_countyname     n2 y2_geoid y1_geoid y2_ling_zo y1_ling_zo ling_mig    i7    i9   i11   i12
                        <char>  <int>   <char>   <char>      <int>      <int>    <num> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1: Autauga County Non-migrants  41198    01001    01001          9          9        0     0  1817   244     0
2: Baldwin County Non-migrants 148883    01003    01003          9          9        0   743     0     0    90
```

If you don't have i7:i12 estimated, and you need to do so from n2, you can

```
# get cts by geoid
cts_by_geoid <- dcast(data = in_1314_sub[, sum(n2), by=.(y2_geoid,g=paste0("i", y1_ling_zo))],
                      formula = y2_geoid~g,
                      value.var="V1")

# merge with non_sof table
in_1314_non_sof[,-c(8,12)][cts_by_geoid, on=.(y2_geoid)]
```

Output, as above

Comment: A little commentary on `dcast` might be helpful for the uninitiated (me), for while I realized I was going from long to wide, I didn't realize it had already been completely accounted for, first [google: r data.table long to wide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) result, though perhaps just the link suffices. Will try on full data and report.

Comment: `-c(8:12)` part of `in_1314_non_sof[, -c(8:12)]` was for de-cluttering the MRE. Thanks for pointing me to `dcast` and the `cts_by_geoid` code that greatly simplified my approach.